# Text Manipulation Split Classes in a Single File into mulitple Files

Tags: c#, text, resharper, file-manipulation, text-manipulation

I used XSD.EXE to to generate a C# files from an XSD schema. Unfortunately, this tool extracts all the classes into a single allClasses.cs file.

Has anyone got a good technique(or tool) that will extract each of the classes in the allClasses.cs file into their own respective file e.g. ClassA.cs, ClassB.cs, etc. ?

Answer (score 6):

Just released ReSharper 5.0 have project-level refactorings.
Right click on the file, Refactor -> Move types into matching files

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re-sharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to separate the classes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169310/is-using-resharper-a-time-saver

Comment: I have to go through each class individually and Right Click -> MOVE. Do you know if there is a way to select all classes and move all to their own file?